# Required custom attributes

Tags: android

android:layout_width and android:layout_height are required attributes, i.e. if you don't specify them for a Layout, Android Studio tells me "Element x doesn't have required attribute android:layout_height."

I'm defining some custom attributes in my own classes and I'd like to require that anyone who uses them in xml specify values just like they have to specify layout_width and layout_height.

How do I do that? Is there something I can add in attrs.xml here:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyStyleable">
   <attr name="myAttribute" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Or maybe in style.xml here:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="myAttribute">3</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AFAIK, currently `attr`s don't have any attributes to mark them mandatory. (`"layout_width"` and the like are very common mistakes, checking for those is wired into the SDK)

You can, however, throw an `RuntimeException` from your custom `View` if an attribute is missing (which you can determine by calling `TypedArray.hasValue()`) -- `TypedArray` does that in `getLayoutDimension()` method.

This is exactly the behavior you get if you compile an app that's missing a `"layout_width"` somewhere using command line tools (i.e. no Eclipse or Idea to detect the missing atrribute and prevent you from compiling): you run the app and it crashes immediately with a `RuntimeException` saying you're missing the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx), there are extension functions that provide `getFloatOrThrow()` and other similar methods.

Check them out [here](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.content.res/android.content.res.-typed-array/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

TypedArray also has a few methods to cover both attribute getting and exception throwing states. Just use them if you want your attribute to be required (not clearly)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5df3426a44c3fa7f7260bcde31a8f5792faa653f/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml). There is info about how is "wrap_content" and "match_parent" defined. Maybe this will help.